# Social - two-way friendship relation

Tags: php, mysql, social-networking, relationship

I have two simple MySQL tables: user & relations.

Relations table:

```
user_id int(10) unsigned    NO  PRI     
friend_id   int(10) unsigned    NO  PRI
```

(part of) User table:

```
id  int(10) unsigned    NO  PRI     
username    varchar(128)    NO
```

I select friend of friends using this query:

```
SELECT f2.friend_id, u.username
FROM relations f1
JOIN relations f2 ON f1.friend_id=f2.user_id
LEFT JOIN user u ON u.id = f2.friend_id
WHERE f2.friend_id NOT IN (select friend_id from relations where user_id=@user_id) AND f1.user_id= 2 AND f2.friend_id!= 2
```

Above query is OK (I think) for one-way relation, where my "friend" don't have to accept friendship. I know it can work in some cases, but I think, that for me it should be two-way.
I know, that "IN" statement's are not very efficient. What is best (fastest? most mysql-server friendly?) way to get friend's, but only those, who have accepted friendship (two records in relations table:

```
user_id:1 + friend_id:2 and user_id:2 + friend_id:1)?
```

Comment: I think do't need to re-join the relations table again.

Comment: You have commentary in the middle of your question which I am trying to understand. Do you want a list of friends for a given user where the friendship is  considered two-way?

Comment: Load a SQLFiddle.com with sample data and let us know which records should and should not be returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you need to LEFT JOIN to the user table? Isn't that a foreign key that would require the record to exist?  For a two-way relationship aren't you just looking for a record in the relations table where the user and friend fields are "swapped"?

```
SELECT f2.friend_id, u.username
FROM relations f1
JOIN relations f2 
  ON f1.friend_id = f2.user_id
    AND f1.user = f2.friend_id
LEFT JOIN user u
  ON u.id = f1.friend_id
WHERE f1.user_id @user_id;
```

Comment: No, because there is a possibility, that I didn't add him as friend. Selecting only "swapped" field's won't work because of this.

Comment: I need to get more 'friend' data from users table and this is why i've used LEFT JOIN

Comment: "I didn't add him as friend" - what does a two way relation mean then?  Doesn't that JOIN ON clause match your example? `user_id:1 + friend_id:2 and user_id:2 + friend_id:1`.  Please revise your question with sample data and the result you want.

Comment: Yes. You're right, and this answer is correct for this question. What I really wanted, is to find friends of my friends, which accepted two-way friendship. Sorry for that.

Comment: Can You help me with searching for friends of friends?

Comment: Load up sqlfiddle.com with sample data. I don't think what you are asking for is overly difficult.  For clarity, you want a list of people that have a two-way relation with people that @user has a two-way relation?

Comment: Yes. I'll load sqlfiddle in few minutes

Comment: @PsychoX - take a look at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eb5c5/14 ~ I created a view for readability based on the above query.  It should find friends of friends (two-way) and then exclude anybody they have in common already via the `NOT EXISTS` clause

Comment: Thank You for help, but unfortunately your query don't show all friends. For example: It does show 3:2 relation, but don't show 3:4

Comment: @PsychoX - 3:4? you did not ask for that.  You asked to show friends of friends in 2way relationship.  4 is a 2way friend of 3.  4 has no other 2way friends, so it is impossible for this query to return a result.  See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c0e5f/1 - I just added the relationship for 4 & 7 which now it shows up using the exact same query.

Comment: I mean, that there are connections to mainfriends, which aren't 
INSERT INTO `relations` VALUES ('3', '2');
INSERT INTO `relations` VALUES ('2', '3');
INSERT INTO `relations` VALUES ('4', '3');
INSERT INTO `relations` VALUES ('5', '3');
INSERT INTO `relations` VALUES ('7', '3');
INSERT INTO `relations` VALUES ('3', '4');
INSERT INTO `relations` VALUES ('3', '5');

Comment: At Your example we can see mainfriends from 3<->2 and 3<->4 relations. But (for example) 3<->5 isn't included. And we have both records for 3->5 and 5->3

Comment: I don't know how to be more clear - you asked to see **friends of friends**.  I am showing you that.  The reason why 3<->5, is not shown is because 5 has no other friends than 3.  __If you add a 2way friend to 5, then it will be shown.__  Are you now asking for 'show a person's 2way friends, AND show that person's friend's 2 way friends'?

Comment: @PsychoX - what do you want the result set to look like?

Comment: Please take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20263362/mysql-get-people-connections-from-database. I created another question and explained everything.